# Can Ivy be configured to require a digest / checksum from a resolver?

Tags: ivy

I am using a filesystem resolver and have it configured to verify an md5 checksum of each artifact if the md5 file exists.

Can I require the md5 checksum file to exist or fail the artifact retrieval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Files that contain checksums to verify other files are called Descriptors in Ivy.

The descriptor attribute on a resolver set to "required" will fail to retrieve modules (artifacts) without a checksum file:

(from an ivysettings.xml file):

```
<resolvers>
  <filestystem name="filesystemresolver" checksums="md5" descriptor="required">
    <ivy pattern.../>
    <artifact pattern.../>
  </filesystem>
</resolvers>
```